# ¿Puedo llamar a clases en JavaFX que creen objetos?

Tags: java, javafx

Llevo un par de días atascado, porque me gustaría saber si los métodos que tengo en mi clase principal de JavaFX que crean HBboxes, Paneles, etc., podría sacarlos a una clase externa para así tenerlo todo más ordenado, pero las maneras que he encontrado de hacerlo sólo lo explican para Java normal, lenguaje en el que sé hacerlo. 
Mi problema es al intentarlo en JavaFX, que al hacer los returns de los métodos me dan errores de todo tipo y no sé solucionarlos.

¿Alguno sabe cómo hacerlo o ha tenido antes este problema?

*Edito siguiendo los consejos de Balbu*

Este es el código de mi clase Cliente:

```
package cliente;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import builder.gridBuilder;

public class Cliente extends Application {

    public gridBuilder gB;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = gB.creaLogin();

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 700, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Room For You");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Y este es el de mi clase gridBuilder, que está en otro paquete por tenerlo todo más ordenado:

```
package builder;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class gridBuilder{

    public GridPane creaLogin(){
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25));
        ImageView logo = new ImageView("imgs/logo.png");
        grid.add(logo, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(logo, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setMargin(logo, new Insets(0, 0, 20, 0));

        Label userName = new Label("Nombre:");
        grid.add(userName, 0, 1);
        TextField userTextFied = new TextField();
        grid.add(userTextFied, 1, 1);
        Label password = new Label("Contraseña:");
        grid.add(password, 0, 2);
        TextField passTextField = new TextField();
        grid.add(passTextField, 1, 2);

        Button btn = new Button("Iniciar Sesión");
        grid.add(btn, 1, 4);

        Text actionTarget = new Text();
        grid.add(actionTarget, 0, 6);
        GridPane.setColumnSpan(actionTarget, 2);
        GridPane.setHalignment(actionTarget, HPos.CENTER);

        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) -> {
            actionTarget.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
            actionTarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
        });

        return grid;
    }

}
```

Me da error al ejecutar el Cliente por InvocationTargetException al llamar a gB.creaLogin()

¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes separar el boton de esta manera:

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton() {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

Y asi tendrias una clase representativa de tu boton propio. Puedes hacer lo mismo con paneles y tener paneles personalizados con los componentes que necesites.

Tambien podrias hacerlo con un builder para todos los tipos de botones que tengas

```
public class ButtonBuilder {

    public Button crearBoton1() {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        });
        return button;
    }

    public Button crearBotonMuestraTexto(String text) {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setText("Say '" + text + "'");
        button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println(text);
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

Esto siempre puedes adaptarlo a lo que necesites, como haciendo los metodos estaticos, parametrizando el ActionEvent para que un mismo metodo pueda crear botones con distintas funciones, etc.

Comment: Pero entonces tendría que crear una clase para cada una de las cosas que quisiera poner, ¿no? ¿No sería contraproducente al final tener tantas clases?

Comment: El crear clases, seria para componentes formados por multiples objetos. Te he puesto el ejemplo del boton porque es el metodo que querias sacar, pero eso lo harias por cada layout de tu aplicacion, siguiendo un modelo MVC. Si lo que quieres es simplemente tener una fabrica de objetos, podrias hacerlo implementando un patron Builder, y tendrias una clase ButtonBuilder que tendria diversos metodos, uno por cada tipo de boton que necesites o incluso metodos parametrizados para asi ahorrar codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Las clases que crean interfaces graficas de javafx deben extender de `import javafx.application.Application`. Ahora si puedes pasarlo a otra clase, pero no puedes hacer esto:

```
public gridBuilder gB;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = gB.creaLogin();
```

Yo me pregunto ¿En que momento llamaste al constructor de `public gridBuilder gB`? Por eso te truena: `gridBuilder gB` es nula asi que no puedes llamar a `creaLogin`.

Tienes que hacer esto: `public gridBuilder gB=new gridBuilder();` 
Ademas todas las clases que vas a crear empiezalas con mayúscula o el compilador te va a llenar de warnings

Comment: Vale. Muchísimas gracias. Siempre cometo el mismo error tonto. Ya me funciona todo!

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que mas te ayudo.